# ¿Como puedo consultar una lista de id's con pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

lo que necesito es consultar un lista de id's de projectos y que pymongo me los devuelva, ahora lo estoy intentando asi.

```py
coll_projects = connDB["coll_projects"].find({"project_id": {"$all": ["12ee1ff9c4104d25882ee219d800d1b8", "f0accc00b6ac45619f49fcaaf8fd5069", "fa926b1c3a264af8be5c421d25e4d62d"]}})
```

Pero no me funciona

Comment: If you use `"$in"` rather than `"$all"`, do you get the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como @rickhg12hs te [comenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578156/como-puedo-consultar-una-lista-de-ids-con-pymongo#comment1022169_578156), el problema es que estás usando el operador de consulta erróneo. El operador [`$all`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) se utiliza para filtrar documentos basados en un campo de tipo Array que contenga **todos** (`$all`) los elementos mencionados en el operador.

Por ejemplo:

```js
db.posts.find({tags: {$all: ['javascript', 'mongodb', 'python']})
```

la consulta anterior devuelve todos los documentos de la colección `posts` que contengan un campo de tipo Array llamado `tags` y que dentro de dicho Array contengan *todos* los valores de la consulta.

Puedes ver el siguiente [Mongo Playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mxGqv0vnipt) como ejemplo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debes usar el operador [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) que te devolverá todos los documentos cuyo campo indicado en la consulta se encuentre **en** el Array pasado al operador `$in`.

En tu caso:

```py
coll_projects = connDB["coll_projects"].find({"project_id": {"$in": ["12ee1ff9c4104d25882ee219d800d1b8", "f0accc00b6ac45619f49fcaaf8fd5069", "fa926b1c3a264af8be5c421d25e4d62d"]}})
```

En el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bH4pz2VEknu) puedes ver un ejemplo, usando los mismos datos del primer ejemplo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero sabes alguna forma de eliminar datos? normalmente hariamos tipo enviar en una projection lo que no queremos recibir